# Sort multidimensional Arrays in PHP ASC by String element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
array (size=3)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'parentId' => int 3
      'name' => string 'z' (length=4)
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'parentId' => int 3
      'name' => string 'a' (length=4)
  9 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'parentId' => int 3
      'name' => string 'd' (length=4)
```

And i have to sort this array ascending by name!
The goal is, to make the array to the following structure:

```
array (size=3)
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'parentId' => int 3
      'name' => string 'a' (length=4)
  9 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'parentId' => int 3
      'name' => string 'd' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'parentId' => int 3
      'name' => string 'z' (length=4)
```

Do you guys have any smart solutions? I've tried to save the keys and the name belongs to the key in a new array, and iterate the ksort'ed array once again, and set the new position:

```
    // Placeholder
    $categoryContainer = array();

    // Iterate all categories
    foreach(self::$categories as $key => $category) {
        $categoryContainer[$category['name']] = $key;
    }

    // Resort by key (category name!)
    ksort($categoryContainer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use usort http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: `uasort($array, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']); })`

Comment: Made it, very appreciated!